# Only last value of a variable goes into \psfrag function

Tags: psfrag, arguments, variable

I make two calls, but it seems like only last value of `\lRaise` goes into the function, so both boxes are raised by -5pt:

```
\newlength{\lRaise}
\setlength{\lRaise}{-0.97pt}
\psfrag{low-order}[B][][0.8]{\raisebox{\lRaise}{молодший}}
\setlength{\lRaise}{-5pt}
\psfrag{high-order}[B][][0.8]{\raisebox{\lRaise}{старший}}
```

I will have pretty many such calls per document. How to pass all values of `\lRaise`?

EDIT: To answer the comment:

```
\newlength{\lOriginal}
\newlength{\lLocal}
\newlength{\lRaise}
\newcommand{\psfragtrans}[2]{
\settodepth{\lOriginal}{#1}
\settodepth{\lLocal}{#2}
\ifdim\lLocal>\lOriginal\setlength{\lRaise}{\dimexpr(\lOriginal-\lLocal)/2\relax}\else\setlength{\lRaise}{0pt}\fi
\psfrag{#1}[B][][0.8]{\raisebox{\lRaise}{#2}}
}
```

Comment: why do you need `\lRaise` here? simplest would just be to use the lengths directly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather odd to be typesetting the PS string but anyway

```
\newlength{\lOriginal}
\newlength{\lLocal}
\newlength{\lRaise}
\newcommand{\psfragtrans}[2]{%%%%
\settodepth{\lOriginal}{#1}%%%%
\settodepth{\lLocal}{#2}%%%%
\ifdim\lLocal>\lOriginal\setlength{\lRaise}{\dimexpr(\lOriginal-\lLocal)/2\relax}\else\setlength{\lRaise}{0pt}\fi
\def\tmp##1{\psfrag{#1}[B][][0.8]{\raisebox{##1}{#2}}}%%%%
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\lRaise}%%%%%
}
```

Comment: I got this `Runaway argument?
{\settodepth {\lOriginal }{##1}\settodepth {\lLocal }{##2}\ifdim \lLocal \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test_psfrag.tex`

Comment: @Yola one extra `}` added to `\def\tmp` sorry.  (You had not provided a usable test file so the code was not tested...)

Comment: Sorry, one more thing here: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \tmp.` Thanks. I think it has something to do with sharps, but can't figure it out.

Comment: @Yola I see you figured it out thanks for fixing, as always do what I mean not what I say:-)